# Microsoft Graph API Send Email With Attachment

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to send an email with an attachment using the Microsoft Graph API and Graph Explorer. I tried submitting the following JSON in the request:

```
{
    "message": {
        "subject": "Meet for lunch?",
        "body": {
            "contentType": "Text",
            "content": "The new cafeteria is open."
        },
        "toRecipients": [
            {
                "emailAddress": {
                    "address": "someemail@gmail.com"
                }
            }
        ],
        "attachments": [
            {
                "name": "test.txt",
                "contentType": "text/plain",
                "contentBytes": "This is a test!"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

But I get the error BadRequest and the following response:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "RequestBodyRead",
        "message": "The property 'contentBytes' does not exist on type 'Microsoft.OutlookServices.Attachment'. Make sure to only use property names that are defined by the type or mark the type as open type.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2023-03-22T20:10:51",
            "request-id": "b51e1acc-f1d5-452c-9162-19f4a34a1213",
            "client-request-id": "39a60671-b8fa-deb7-560f-8e5d8b50c7ba"
        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Attachments` in the request body has description [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/message?view=graph-rest-1.0#relationships) and it points to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/fileattachment?view=graph-rest-1.0), it mentioned:

> When creating a file attachment, include the following in the request
> body:
>
> "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.fileAttachment" The required
> properties name and contentBytes.

And about the `contentBytes` property, it has description: `contentBytes    Edm.Binary  The base64-encoded contents of the file.`.

Let's see the [official sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-sendmail?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#request-2), I'm afraid your issue resulted from missing `@odata.type` and didn't use `base64-encoded contents` for `contentBytes`.

```
"attachments": [
      {
        "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.fileAttachment",
        "name": "attachment.txt",
        "contentType": "text/plain",
        "contentBytes": "SGVsbG8gV29ybGQh"
      }
    ]
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the type of attachments (there can be three different types of Attachments in Exchange FileAttachment,ItemAttachment,ReferanceAttachment) and you also need to Base64Encode the contentBytes so in you example the following should work

```
{
"message": {
    "subject": "Meet for lunch?",
    "body": {
        "contentType": "Text",
        "content": "The new cafeteria is open."
    },
    "toRecipients": [
        {
            "emailAddress": {
                "address": "someemail@gmail.com"
            }
        }
    ],
    "attachments": [
        {
            "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.fileAttachment",
            "name": "test.txt",
            "contentType": "text/plain",
            "contentBytes": "VGhpcyBpcyBhIHRlc3Qh"
        }
    ]
}
```

}